# How to put a text and a string inside array

Tags: php, arrays, string, text

I've create this code

```
 $S_Jenis = $_POST['JenisTrx'];
 $S_Keterangan = $_POST['KeteranganTrx'];
 $S_Jumlah = $_POST['JumlahTrx'];
```

and I call it here

```
$msg = array
      (
    'body'  => $S_Keterangan Rp$S_Jumlah,
    'title' => Kas $S_Jenis,
            'icon'  => 'myicon',
            'sound' => 'mySound'
      );
```

but it's an error if I put "Kas" inside title and 2 String inside body, anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: `'title' => 'Kas' . $S_Jenis`. The same in line above, PHP basic and string concatenation.

Comment: What should `Kas` do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try Following code

```
$msg = array
      (
    'body'  => $S_Keterangan ."Rp".$S_Jumlah,
    'title' => "Kas".$S_Jenis,
            'icon'  => 'myicon',
            'sound' => 'mySound'
      );
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to concatenate these strings:

```
$msg = array(
  'body'  => $S_Keterangan . ' Rp' . $S_Jumlah,
  'title' => 'Kas' . $S_Jenis,
  'icon'  => 'myicon',
  'sound' => 'mySound'
);
```

To read about string concatenation in PHP, see: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php